# Meaning of Docker command

Tags: docker, command, docker-registry

It seems a simple question but it's really not clear what the meaning is of this command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

The `-v pwd/certs:/certs \`is not clear at all.
Could someone give an explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### explanation

```
`pwd` - shell command to show current path, normally you can replace with $(pwd)
```

So `-v pwd/certs:/certs`  means, mount the current path's subpath certs to docker container's folder /certs

For each line has backslash `\` in the end, is used for long input

Comment: So acutally this is including my certificate in the docker container?

Comment: yes, so your current folder has the `certs` folder? It will be mounted to docker container as `/certs`

Answer (score 3):

In Docker, images are loaded into the container using '**run**' command 
'**docker run -d -p 5000:5000**'  this line of command shows the container is going to run as daemon service(-d) means it will start the container in background automatically. -p is assigning ports for your container as **BMW** says 'pwd' will give the current directory -v will assign our host's folder path to Container's folder path. You are all set for using your Container. Happy Coding!